# Uploading picture seems down across all stack website

Tags: support, status-completed, imgur

It seems not possible to upload a picture anymore across several StackExchange website.

It fails with "Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur" although the host *i.stack.imgur.com* is responding properly.

Other users confirmed the issue.

Comment: We're aware of an issue in some parts of the world and are investigating now

Comment: [tag:status-reproduced] from Germany. Would show a picture, but ... :P

Comment: Man . Someone's going to be having a interesting day

Comment: Seems to be working again for me.

Comment: Working for me too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of our ISP links to the NY data center was flapping which meant any traffic in or out of the data center to certain parts of the world was not being routed correctly. That affected our connectivity to Imgur who hosts our images. For now we've disabled that link and all traffic is being routed over our other ISPs

Comment: Ah the joy of flapping links 