# Can't upload image in Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, images, uploader

When I try to upload an image in the Stack Exchange iOS app, I'm getting this error:

> #### Request failed
>
> An unknown error occurred. Please try again in a few minutes.

[image]

I've already tried:

- Logging in and out
- Switching between WiFi and 4G network
- Flying from Amsterdam (the Netherlands) to Bordeaux (France)

but to no avail.

The app receives the following error message from the server:

```
{"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error","error_id":500}
```

It might be related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327432/295232), but that's a bug from April and I'm sure it worked for me until [two days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1832251/2). [This bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328174/295232) might be related but is marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and I *am* able to upload images via the website (proof: see the image above). I'm not sure if everybody is affected by this bug, as [this chat message shows](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7717774).

Comment: Being in the US doesn't help, either. And I haven't uploaded anything recently. Seems broken. I'm checking with Brian.

Comment: Taking an international flight to test a bug, now _that_ is dedication </joke>

Comment: Related or dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326797/photo-upload-on-ios-app-in-gardening-exchange-fails-most-of-the-time.

Comment: @Catija Adam looked into a similar bug not long ago, maybe worth checking out with him as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed.  There were configuration changes and the server needed to be cycled.